# AS3 - Anonymous function 'this'

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have played around with some Anonymous functions, and I noticed that this code does not trace the same thing twice:

```
public function Main() 
    {
        trace(this);

        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(e:Event):void
        {
            trace(this);
        });
    }
```

The first trace traces "[object Main]" and the second one traces "[object Global]" (after I clicked). Why does that happen? And what is object Global, is it useful for something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An anonymous function allows you to create variations to behavior, without having to create a subclass, or some complicate switch statements, so you can now simply assign a function to perform a certain task at **runtime**. Is like any **variable** - only this special kind of variable doesn't have a value, but a behavior.

```
//clasic
bar = function(arg1, arg2, etc) {
    // do something here      
}
```

when you `trace(this)` you refere to what function returns and that's a special global **'bar'** variable.
The standard example for this is event listeners, but you can also apply this to any other functionality you desire.

You can find out about anonymous functions here : http://blogs.adobe.com/simplicity/2007/10/post.html.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the keyword `this` represents the `global object`, some alternate universe where your function was created, because it was defined outside any custom class or object.

**Main class**

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Main extends MovieClip
    {
        public function Main()
        {
            // trace(this);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(e:MouseEvent):void
            {
                trace(this);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**output**

```
[object global]
```

In the following example, the function listener `toClick` is defined as `method of the Main class`, so `this` refers to the `object Main`.

**Correct code**

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Main extends MovieClip
    {
        public function Main()
        {
            // trace(this);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, toClick);
        }

        private function toClick(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            trace(this); 
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
[object Main]
```